# Android layouts view scrollable texts in a page with other buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to make a page with scrollable texts. I am using an relative layout an linear layout and a scroll. But somehow the texts are not paint from begining.

The first 3 lines are not drawn (Title1,Title2, Title3) because they are outside the scroll area. But why? The scroll works/shows fine in the specified area from 2 buttons like below:
I set here      android:layout_below="@id/button_s"
        android:layout_above="@id/button_c" the margins of the scroll but still the text is displays outside the margins. What I do wrong? Why linear layout lin2 in which I draw the texts starts from top of the screen? I set for it android:layout_below.

Here is my code:

main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/my_app" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_s"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv"
    android:text="@string/search" />   

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_c"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/config" />

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/button_s"
    android:layout_above="@id/button_c" android:id="@+id/ScrollView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"                      
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/lin2" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_below="@id/button_s"
        android:layout_above="@id/button_c"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

my java file:

```
String[] strTitles  ={"Title 1: test test test test test test test test",
                       "Title 2:  test test test test test",
                       "Title 3:  test test test test test",
                       "Title 4:  test test test test",
                       "Title 5:  test test test",
                       "Title 6:  test test test test",
                       "Title 7:  test test test test",
                       "Title 8:  test test test test test",
                       "Title 9:  test test test test test",
                       "Title 9:  test test test test test",
                       "Title 10:  test test test test",
                       "Title 11:  test test test test test",
                       "Title 12:  test test test test test",
                       "Title 13:  test test test test test",
                       "Title 14:  test test "};
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lin2);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < strTitles.length * 2 ; i++)
    {
        String strToDisplay = " ";
        if(i%2 == 1)
            strToDisplay = " ";
        else
        {
            strToDisplay = strTitles[i/2];
        }

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(strToDisplay);
        ll.addView(tv);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `layout_gravity` to `center_horizontal` only for the *lin2* `LinearLayout`:

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

I don't understand why you would also put `center_vertical` when the parent `ScrollView` height is set to `wrap_content`.

Comment: @Dorian you can also use "\n" in your loop. for (int i = 0 ; i < strTitles.length; i++)
     {
         TextView tv = new TextView(this);
         tv.setText(strTitles[i] + "\n");
         ll.addView(tv);
         tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
     }